# Orbits of the $\text{SL}(n,\mathcal{O}_K)$-action on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(K)$ for a number field $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading some [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/SL2classno.pdf) of Keith Conrad where he proves that the number of orbits of the $\text{SL}(2,\mathcal{O}_K)$-action on $\mathbb{P}^{1}(K)$ for a number field $K$ is precisely the class number of $K$.

I am wondering if there is any kind of "higher-order" arithmetic information found in looking at the number of orbits of the $\text{SL}(n,\mathcal{O}_K)$-action on $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(K)$ for $n>2$ (or even on higher Grassmannians $\text{Gr}(r,K^{n})$, but let's not get too crazy for now). As a first question, will these numbers even be finite for all $n$?

For $K=\mathbb{Q}$, I believe one can use a generalized Euclidean algorithm to show that the action above is transitive for all $n$, at least for the projective spaces $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(\mathbb{Q})$, but I'm not sure if one can adapt this argument to work even for $\mathcal{O}_K$ that are UFDs but not Euclidean.

Does anyone know of any references on this question?

Comment: Let me understand tittle first, I'll answer you after lol

Comment: @Shadock "Neither jot nor tittle, dude!" :) Yeah, it's a wee-bit technical. :) But, luckily, there are some techno-tough-people who can protect the civilians from this sort of intellectuo-violence, so, ... well, just salute! :)

Comment: @paulgarrett it was just for fun, I have no problem with abstraction ;)

Comment: @Shadock, :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm a little nervous about that assertion being exactly right, due to distinctions about "narrow class group", and so on, but I don't want to think about it...

The relevant factoid is "Steinitz' Theorem", generalizing the structure theorem for finitely-generated modules over principal ideal domains to finitely-generated modules over Dedekind domains $\mathfrak o$: among other things, the torsion-free ones are of the form $\mathfrak o\oplus\ldots\oplus \mathfrak o\oplus \mathfrak a$ for some ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $\mathfrak o$. And subsidiary points like $\mathfrak a\oplus \mathfrak b\approx \mathfrak o\oplus \mathfrak a\mathfrak b$.

The $SL_n(\mathfrak o)$ or $GL_n(\mathfrak o)$ action is then just about change-of-basis.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the response. I don't immediately see how this relates to elements of $\mathbb{P}^{n}(K)$. Could you please add some clarification here? Also in response to another comment of yours -- is my question too "technical" for this forum? Is there another location that would be better?

Comment: (No, your question is fine for this forum...) The action of $SL_{n+1}(k)$ on $\mathbb P k^n$ is by generalized linear fractional transformations. Given a point in homogeneous coords, first get rid of the denominators to put it in $\mathfrak o^{n+1}$, then use the action of $SL_{n+1}(\mathfrak o)$.